# Android - Possible to update image in loop?

Tags: java, android, for-loop

I have the following code but the image only updates after the loop has completed not during the loop like it would in normal java - moving the image across the screen my increasing the X location. Is there anyway to make the image update during the Loop???
Thanks Again/

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button button;
    ImageView image;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        addListenerOnButton();
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {
        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeImage);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                //image.setImageResource(R.drawable.android);

                int X = 0;
                int Y = 0;
                //for(;;) {
                for ( int i = 0; i < 50 ; i++) {
                    image.setX(i);
                    image.setY(Y);
                    setContentView(R.layout.main);
                    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.android3d);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove `setContentView(R.layout.main);
                image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1)` lines then try

Comment: Use an animator https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import android.os.Handler;


for ( int i = 0; i < 50 ; i++) {    
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                image.setX(i);
                image.setY(Y);
                setContentView(R.layout.main);
                image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.android3d);
        }
    }, 200);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply line new Handler().post(new Runnable() { is highlighted red as in this image = https://postimg.org/image/nafrsd7vr/

Comment: Thanks again for your Reply it still doesn't update during the Loop - I might have to explore some other options.